# How to download a file from ftp server to local machine using java

Tags: java, ftp, download

I want to download a zip file from FTP server to my local machine.

And that .zip file folder structure is like *a\b\c\d.zip*.

Please help me to do that

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check VFS library - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs//

Answer (score 5):

The following post/blog/link explains how to download file using Apache Commons Net

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/03/apache-commons-ftpclient-java-example_16.html

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/32031-ftp-in-java-using-apache-commons-net/

Hope it helps.